# Flutter: moving files from local machine

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you use flutter to move files from local machine? For example from `C:\images\photo.png` to `C:\photos\photo.png`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make files moving using Dart/Flutter, you need to import `dart:io` :

```
import "dart:io";
```

then you can use this method, you can understand what it does with the comments I wrote.

```
 Future<File> moveFile(File originalFile, String targetPath) async {
  try {
    // This will try first to just rename the file if they are on the same directory, 
    return await originalFile.rename(targetPath);

  } on FileSystemException catch (e) {
    // if the rename method fails, it will copy the original file to the new directory and then delete the original file
    final newFileInTargetPath = await originalFile.copy(targetPath);
    await originalFile.delete();
    return newFileInTargetPath;
  }
}
    
  final file = File("C:/images/photo.png");
  final path = "C:/photos/";
  await moveFile(file, path);
```

However, I will explain here what it does :

If your file is under the same path directory, then there is no need to move it, just rename them with the `rename()` method will work, if the file is in an else directory on your system, it will create a new `File` where it will copy that file to that path, Now we will have two copies of that `File`, one under the old path and the other under the new path, so we need to delete the old one with the `delete()` method, finally we returned the new file with `return newFile;`

Comment: The method outputs error `Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'targetPath', path = 'originalFile' (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` but the file has not been moved

Comment: path = 'originalFile' why the originalFile is String here,

Comment: can you share with me what code with the path and file object did you tried